# How to Store an int in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

In my first app, I am putting together a simple counter app where user taps a button to add one point to an `int` variable. I have tried to store the number of button taps permanently as a share preference but the result is not stored and it is reset to 0 each time the app is run agian. Here's my code. I really appreciate if you help me.

```
public class counter extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int greed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SharedPreferences counter = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("uk.me.forus.lifetracker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        counter.edit().putInt("greed", greed).apply();
        Log.i("Test: ", Integer.toString(counter.getInt("greed", greed)));

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);
    }

    public void greed (View view){

        greed += 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: can you mention what type of error you are getting

Comment: Hi Ragul - I do get any error as it is. The problem is that the value of "greed" varaible does not get stored in the Shared Preferences.

Comment: move your super.onCreate and setContentView to top before using shared preference.

Comment: Hi Ragul, thanks for your help. it solved the issue, Can you tell me if Shared preferences are limitted to their defined activities (Are they global)? I have two activities and trying to use one shared preferences value in one activity to set a variable in anouther acticities, I cannot define sharedactivites as Static. Thanks for your help.

Comment: they are global. you can use them anywhere in your app. Note if you uninstall the app shared preference data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You're saving the `greed` in the `onCreate()` method at the beginning. At that time, the value of the variable greed is 0 as it has not yet been initialized. Therefore, this value 0 gets stored. You're never updating the value of greed thereafter. Therefore, it remains 0.

Try this:

```
private int greed;
private SharedPreferences counter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);

    counter = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("uk.me.forus.lifetracker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //start the value of greed from what it was earlier.
    greed = counter.getInt("greed",0);

}

public void greed (View view){

    greed += 1;

    //update and print the value of greed everytime you increment it:
    counter.edit().putInt("greed", greed).apply();
    Log.i("Test: ", Integer.toString(counter.getInt("greed", greed)));

}
```